# DocuSign SOAP error: This Account lacks sufficient permissions

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I am using soap to call CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates. I am embedding the security header at the top and I am getting the response below. Any ideas on what could be wrong.

**My security header is:**

```html
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>981ec272-3f9a-4cd8-83a9-062f82fce46c</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">abcdefgh</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
```

**The Response is:**

This Account lacks sufficient permissions.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/fault</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:2a38012a-5ae0-4077-8b81-08a808c62e60</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:6c1f1484-c546-49be-b181-4d75f5dd08a5</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-10879099-ff09-4aa8-bcb8-7f2cf8819781">
            <wsu:Created>2019-01-08T16:04:53Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2019-01-08T16:09:53Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>This Account lacks sufficient permissions. </faultstring>
         <faultactor>missing in Web.Config</faultactor>
         <detail>
            <ErrorCode xmlns="missing in Web.Config">111</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorReason xmlns="missing in Web.Config">This Account lacks sufficient permissions.</ErrorReason>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please list the full API Endpoint you are hitting, including if this is a demo request or production request.  You can redact any private IDs or info if there is any...

Comment: This is demo environment. Endpoint is https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?WSDL

Comment: Are you positive that you are passing in valid credentials through your code?  Can you confirm that you are able to login to your DocuSign sandbox using that same email + pwd combo?

Comment: I am positive. I login manually with my email address and password. The soap api asks me for the API Username and password. When I passed in other credentials initially, it barks at me and lets me know that either my id or password are invalid or both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to embed your Integrator Key in the Username element, using brackets.  Most of the examples shown in the authentication section of the SOAP API guide pre-date Integrator Keys and don't show it for UsernameToken.

Example:

```
<wsse:Username>[BILL- 9048-469a-a9e9-211cef79e5f3]2988541c-4ec7-4245-b520-f2d324062ca3</wsse:Username>
```